# iPHONE: This is not a test user accout please create a new account in the sandbox environment ERROR

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have created an iphone application with in-app purchase.

5 out of 10 users are reporting the following message when they try to buy something using in-app purchase:

> This is not a test user accout please
>   create a new account in  the sandbox
>   environment.

I have tested the in-app purchase and I never got such error.

any clues?

any help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Are any of the users using jailbroken iPhones? have they got MobileMe/iTunes accounts enabled? Did you try the iPhone Developer Forums yet? (It's private, so no Google search will find it)

Comment: 1. probably yes..... 2. I don't know....... 3. not yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jasiaren comment up there is the answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an ad-hoc or distro build? Is the product cleared for distribution in iTunes Connect? You'll see that message if you try to purchase a product before it's been green-lit for release.

Comment: And did you remember to switch from the sandbox store to the production store?

Comment: [Bet Gottlieb] - yes the application is being sold for weeks and so the in-app objects. Everything is approved and working on the store. 
 :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[nduplessis] - as far as I know there's no such thing as switch from sandbox to the production store. The sandbox mode enters automatically if you run the application from Xcode. All apps sold on the store are, automatically, on the production store...

Comment: can this be related to jailbroken iphones in some way?

Comment: I know that jailbreaking screws with receiving push notifications, and since in-app purchases are similar in the way that they're managed by Apple, it could prove a problem when a jailbroken device tries to use in-app purchasing..