# In App Purchase error "This is not a Test User account"

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, jailbreak, storekit

I've successfully implemented In App Purchasing and 99,9% of the users successfully buy the IAP product. However, one user with a jailbroken phone gets this error:

[image: This is not a Test User account. Please create a new account in the Sandbox environment. Environment: Sandbox]

Is there anything I can suggest to this user? I don't think the problem exists for all jailbroken iPhones because the number of complaints should be statistically higher, then.

There's another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2058978/235297) though it wasn't clear about the jailbreaking status of affected users. I'm searching for an actual solution for those jailbroken device users (other than recommending not to jailbreak - since that'd mean lost business).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a how-to [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdN2oRtBjNA) that proposes a solution for the problem by temporarily replacing /var/stash/libexec.*/installd by /var/stash/libexec.*/installd.new. However, this approach bricked the phone of one user so the OS had to be restored and jailbroken again (at least the IAP worked after the restore)! I absolutely don't recommend this solution but it might be a last resort for some hard core jailbreakers - after all, jailbreakers should know what they're doing, right?

Answer (score 1):

This happens every now and then with jailbroken devices trying to use the store. Apple knows the device is no longer legitimate so the request to the store is in "test mode".

You could tell him a few things:

- if you're sure you're app can be purchased with other jailbreaks isolate which he's using and tell him to use the other ones
- add his user account as a "test user" on your list. You won't get paid but you'll have a happy customer
- tell him not to jailbreak his phone...

Possibly send him a build of the app with his device and consider him a QA tester. He'd have to send you his device id and you could make him a speciL build every 3-4 months.

Comment: Thanks. Although not a real solution, you're offering good advice how to work around the issue. +1

Comment: Thanks...wish I could help but it would involve really getting into the meat of the jailbreaking code and hacking within that, right? Cool solution though.